# How to join attributes by location with command line?

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, pyqgis, ogr

I would like to join the attributes of two shapefiles by location but with a command line (Linux).
This feature is easy in QGIS but it is VERY slow.

Is there a way of doing this with ogr or PyQGIS?

Comment: Have you considered to add PostGIS (and learn SQL ) to your toolbox ?

Comment: Yes but let's say... next year ! I need first to get use to classe, objet, database.... and then I guess I will be ready for PostGIS. In the meanwhile, easy sql statement like the one used in ogr2ogr are ok to me

Comment: @MappaGnosis,I had a look on ogr2ogr documentation, putting a shape file to PosGIS seems quite easy. `ogr2ogr -f “PostgreSQL” PG:”host=myhost user=myloginname dbname=mydbname password=mypassword” myshapefile.shp`. Do you have a solution for me in that case ? Thank you

Comment: You can do it that way, or PostGIS comes with a plugin (PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader) which can make life even easier.  Just watch the encoding - I usually need to explicitly set it to 'LATIN1'.

Comment: And then, how can I perform the joint by location ?

Answer (score 3):

These kinds of queries can run quicker with a spatial index. If the file is from Esri, it may have `.sbn` and `.sbx` files, which OGR 1.10 can use. However, if you've created/modified the shapefile with QGIS, you may need to create/update a `.qix` spatial index. You can find some buttons in QGIS' Layer Properties, under General > Coordinate reference system, look for <kbd>Create spatial index</kbd> and <kbd>Update extents</kbd>. Or from a shell, similar:

```
ogrinfo -sql "CREATE SPATIAL INDEX ON \"your-geoms\"" your-geoms.shp
```

Either method will create/update a `.qix`, which is a quadtree spatial index file.

Once you have a good spatial index, QGIS and other OGR-related things should have better spatial join performance. And for a spatial join from a command line, see [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/119404/1872).