# Problem intersecting shapefiles with OGR in Python

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, intersection

I'm trying to move from ArcPy for geoprocessing. After searching some posts, I found this solution using the GDAL/OGR Python bindings:

[Intersect Shapefiles using Shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119374/intersect-shapefiles-using-shapely/119404#119404)

My code is the following:

```
import os
act_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print act_dir

from osgeo import ogr

ogr.UseExceptions()
ogr_ds = ogr.Open(os.path.join(act_dir,r'data'), True)  
SQL = """\
    SELECT ST_Intersection(A.geometry, B.geometry) AS geometry, A.*, B.*
    FROM Central_America_24h A, municipios_simp_WGS84_dptos_n B
    WHERE ST_Intersects(A.geometry, B.geometry);
"""

layer = ogr_ds.ExecuteSQL(SQL, dialect='SQLITE')
# copy result back to datasource as a new shapefile
layer2 = ogr_ds.CopyLayer(layer, 'mylayer')
#save, close
layer = layer2 = ogr_ds = None
```

I have a folder called 'data', which contains the file 'Central_America_24h.shp' (point shapefile) and 'municipios_simp_WGS84_dptos_n.shp' (polygon shapefile). I want to intersect the points with the polygons and assign them their attributes. It seems the problem is when I try to save the result and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pyAnaconda\puntos_de_calor_test\puntos_calor_tes2t.py", line 39, in <module>
    layer2 = ogr_ds.CopyLayer(layer, 'mylayer')
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 815, in CopyLayer
    return _ogr.DataSource_CopyLayer(self, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.
```

I have checked the documentation, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

[OGRLayer * OGRDataSource::CopyLayer](http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/classOGRDataSource.html#a42dc7f7f538cd4f083af350722fe53ae)

Does anyone know what is causing the problem?

Comment: any reason that you don't want to use `ogr2ogr` as outlined in the link that you included in your post?

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to avoid using an os.system.call and don´t want to install OGR. I have already installed the GDAL/OGR python bindings and would like to use them for this purpose.

Comment: I wonder how you can use GDAL python bindings if you do not have GDAL installed. Not advising to use os.system.call, though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about GDAL. Yes, I have GDAL installed, and  found the ogr2ogr executable in the site_packages folder of my Python installation. But I would like to use the GDAL python bindings if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not understand why beginners try to start with  the GDAL/OGR Python bindings (not very "Pythonic" and difficult) when other easier alternatives are available.

With your script, you need to know `osgeo.ogr` and the SQL dialect of SQLite. The solution proposed by [Mike T](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1872/mike-t) is powerful but not "classic" and performs only the intersection of shapefiles.

What you are trying to do is a Spatial Join (point in Polygon) and not a simple intersection and you can use :

- [pyshp (shapefile)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp) (pure Python module) as in [Point in Polygon](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/01/point-in-polygon.html) or [Point in Polygon 2: Walking the line](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/08/point-in-polygon-2-on-line.html)
- [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html) (other Python binding of OGR with Python dictionaries) and [Shapely](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html) as in [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc (1)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103066/2581) and many other examples in GIS SE
- [GeoPandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas) as in [More Efficient Spatial join in Python without QGIS, ArcGIS, PostGIS, etc (2)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165413/2581)
- If you want to use OGR, consult the [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/index.html) and many examples in GIS SE

Comment: Shapefile iteself has its limit. So relying on GDAL APIs seems to be a long term strategy.