# How to select polygons by criteria and save them to shp file?

Tags: ogr

I have file of polygons  and want to select few by criteria  - area more or less then specific number    and save   result to  shp file.

code  gives 0   by passing criteria:

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

shpFile = 'ReBu.shp'

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ptsDS = driver.Open(shpFile)
ptsLayer = ptsDS.GetLayer()


for i in range(0, ptsLayer.GetFeatureCount()):
    pt = ptsLayer.GetNextFeature()
    print pt.GetField('Area_ha')

myQuery = 'Area_ha = 39.8953'
ptsLayer.SetAttributeFilter(myQuery)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's *always* risky to attempt equivalence operations on floating-point values.  Even if the value displays "39.8953", it's likely to be stored as "39.8952999999999999997" or "39.895300000000000001".  The only safe way to compare against floating-point values is perform range-checking:

```
myQuery = 'Area_ha >= 39.89525 and Area_ha < 39.89535'
```

Depending on the driver, you might be able to use an absolute value function to change the expression:

```
myQuery = 'abs(Area_ha - 39.8953) < 0.00005'
```

though this sort of query would not be able to use an attribute index, and would therefore run much slower.

Answer (score 2):

Be modern, use easiest modules for that (look at [Problem intersecting shapefiles with OGR in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/176582/2581))

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
import fiona
with fiona.open("ReBu.shp") as input:
    meta = input.meta
    with fiona.open('result.shp', 'w',**meta) as output:
       for feature in input:
         if abs(shape(feature['geometry']).area - 39.8953) < 0.00005:
             output.write(feature)
```

1) open the shapefile with [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html): all the features are Python dictionaries
2) copy the properties (geometry, crs, fields definitions) of the original shapefile
3) create a new shapefile with these properties
4) transform the record geometry to a [shapely](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html) geometry (for the area)
5) use the test of Vince
6) if True, write the record to the new shapefile