# Extract intersections of 2 shapefiles with field subset in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have 2 polygon shapefiles: A (with integer field `"a_id"`) and B (integer field `"b_id"`).

My goal is to extract intersections of polygons in layer A with polygons in layer B where attribute `"a_id"` is equal to attribute `"b_id" + 55`.

I'm trying to implement it with the QGIS graphical modeler, but `"Select by expression"` algorithm supports only one layer for running expressions, and `"Extract by location"` has no attribute filter.

Comment: Could you compute all intersections first and then check the attributes?

Comment: @underdark I've tried it but calculating all intersections is quite computation-intense on a large volumes of data and it felt like there should definitely exist easier ways to do the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution for me was to open directory containing both layers as a single [GDALDataset](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html) object, make an [OGR SQL query](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html) to it and save the result to a new layer. It allows doing spatial and attribute queries simultaneously and can be done with the QGIS console:

```
from osgeo import ogr
ogr.UseExceptions()
ogr_ds = ogr.Open('/path/to/data', True)  # Windows: r'C:\path\to\data'
SQL = """\
    SELECT ST_Intersection(A.geometry, B.geometry) AS geometry, A.a_id, B.b_id
    FROM A, B
    WHERE ST_Intersects(A.geometry, B.geometry)
    AND CAST(A.a_id as INTEGER) = CAST(B.b_id as INTEGER) + 55;"""
layer = ogr_ds.ExecuteSQL(SQL, dialect='SQLITE')
# copy result back to datasource as a new shapefile
layer2 = ogr_ds.CopyLayer(layer, 'result_shapefile')
# save, close
layer = layer2 = ogr_ds = None
```

The idea was picked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/119404/34438)